# Do Mysql close the connection in 6.3.6 when I disposed the connection in c# (Mysqlconnection)

Tags: c#, mysql

I thing when people consider about database connection most of time they talk about Sqlconnection come within System.Data namespace.

Last time on a forum I read that even you are using() in MySQL you need to call conn.close();

Not sure about this. I am unsure about it in the case of MySQL. I have some C# code which connect to MySQL.

This code open some connection which they never closed. I want to check the code. How I can verified that connection is closed.

I means first of all how to verify using() close the mysqlconnection automatically.
Secondly How I can debug the code which still not close the connection.

Do someone have good way to know where connection open and not closed.

```
  MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNSTRING);
            cnn.Open();


            using (cnn)
{
}
```

I have added this sample code to know if someone can tell me if this will automatically closed the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source codes of MySql Connector for Dot Net are available from [MySql Site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.5.html#downloads). If you download them and look at the Dispose method of MySqlConnection you see:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (State == ConnectionState.Open)
    Close();
  base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

But I must point out that this is the source for the version 6.5.6. I cannot find the source codes for version 6.3.6. However a previous version (6.1.6) has the same code.

And looking at your code I find it a bit strange and dangerous.
Usually the common usage pattern is the following

```
using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(Globals.CONNSTRING))
{
    cnn.Open();
    ......
}
```

In this way, if the Open fais the connection will be disposed. while in your code this will not happen because you never enter the using statement.

Finally, this is the IL code generated by your code above (added just a FAKE and invalid connection string)

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "test"
IL_0005:  newobj      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor
IL_000A:  stloc.0     // cnn
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // cnn
IL_000C:  callvirt    System.Data.Common.DbConnection.Open
IL_0011:  ldloc.0     // cnn
IL_0012:  stloc.1     // CS$3$0000
IL_0013:  leave.s     IL_001F
IL_0015:  ldloc.1     // CS$3$0000
IL_0016:  brfalse.s   IL_001E
IL_0018:  ldloc.1     // CS$3$0000
IL_0019:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_001E:  endfinally
```

No surprise then. The Connection is closed and disposed

Comment: Is this means no matter if I open the connection inside using or outside the using(). both will dispose and close the connection.

Comment: Yes, it is the object inside the using that will be disposed, your code is bit strange and Dangerous. If it fails to open the connection the using will do nothing to dispose and close.

Comment: @Steve How could I view the IL from an application? What application are you using?

Comment: @Steve One more confusion, what about If I return something within using like using(){return 1} then it will dispose the element.

Comment: The using statement is equivalent to write `try{...}finally{...}`. If you return when inside a try block and a finally block exists, then the finally block is always executed. So, yes, the connection is closed and disposed if you return from inside a using block